# Segfault on execvp using command line arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, execvp

I am working on a programming assignment that ask me to write a code able to read a command from the command line, together with its argument, and execute the program using the execvp.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char **cmd;
    int i;

    if (argc == 1){

        fprintf(stdout, "No command inserted!\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }

    cmd = (char **) malloc( argc * sizeof(char *));
    cmd[0] = strdup(argv[1]);

    if (argc > 2){

    for (i = 1 ; i < argc - 1  ; i++ ){

            cmd[i] = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[i+1]) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(cmd[i], argv[i+1]);

    }

    cmd[argc] = NULL;
    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    cmd[1] = NULL;

    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine typing no arguments command such as:

```
./a.out who
./a.out ls
```

but result in a 'Segmentation Fault:11' when writing commands like:

```
./a.out ls -l
./a.out more file.txt
```

I can't figure out where is the problem...

Comment: I can run your code with ls -l perfectly fine, no changes

Comment: what machine are you using??

Comment: ubuntu using gcc compiler

Comment: @Tyler: that the code does not crash at a particular machine does not mean that it is free of undefined behaviour. In case of UB (as contained in this program), execution *may* crash, but it may also do something else, it may even "work".

Comment: regarding: `cmd[i] = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[i+1]) * sizeof(char) );`  1) the returned type from the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the function `strlen()` returns the index to the terminating NUL byte, but indexes start with 0, so need to use `+1` to get the correct length. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  4) the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  So using that expression just clutters the code.

Comment: when `execvp()` encounters an error and returns, it sets `errno` to indicate the cause of the error.  So best to display the related error message.  So the code can benefit by replacing this line: `fprintf(stderr, "Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");` with `perror( " execvp Failed Execution or not existing command!!\n");`  which will output to stderr, the enclosed text, followed by the system error message.

Comment: @Tyler, the posted code contains (at least) two instances of undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior means that anything can happen including the code 'seems' to work.

Comment: hint:  why bother to copy the contents of the command line.  Could much easier just use:  `execvp( argv[1], argv+sizeof( char * ));`

Comment: the posted code has some memory leaks.  There is also a logic problem as the original process is replaced by the process started with `execvp()`.  Strongly suggest:  call `fork()` to start a new process, then in the 'child' process call `execvp()`  and in the parent process, call `free()` for each of those areas allocated by `malloc()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two points where you exceed array bounds:

```
cmd[i] = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[i+1]) * sizeof(char) )
```

is one off as it does not consider the terminating `\0`-character, such that a `strcpy(cmd[i], argv[i+1])` then will exceed the bounds. Write ...

```
cmd[i] = (char *) malloc( (strlen(argv[i+1]) + 1) * sizeof(char) )
```

instead. BTW: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition.

Further,

```
cmd = (char **) malloc( argc * sizeof(char *));
...
cmd[argc] = NULL;
```

is again one off. It should be `cmd = (char **) malloc( (argc+1) * sizeof(char *))` when you like to assign `cmd[argc] = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. execvp() appeared to do nothing, but in fact the child process I ran it under was crashing with a segfault. The fix ended up being fixing char arrays I'd used to store different transformations of the input. I hadn't used malloc() at all for some of these arrays (I am not a C person and am not proud of that mistake), which only became an issue as the program grew more complex. For the general user brought here, I would advise checking carefully for unallocated pointers or, as above, for pointers with insufficient size. This happened to me even though the array passed to execvp() was properly allocated and had the needed contents (as determined through GDB) with the right types.